# Help with Interchanging Limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How can I evaluate:

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^2}\left|\frac{\sin(mN)}{\sin(m)}\right|\right)$$

I know that we have  $\left|\dfrac{\sin(mN)}{\sin(m)}\right|\leq N$, though I'm sort of worried about interchanging the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean $\lim_{N\to\infty} ...$, but even then the equality isn't enough, because all you get is:

$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=1}^\infty ( \frac{1}{m^2}|\frac{\sin(mN)}{\sin(m)}| ) \le \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=1}^\infty ( \frac{1}{m^2}N ) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

This is not zero, so it does not even imply that there is a limit, as it might oscillate.

Answer (score 0):

With the same assumptions as user21820, I have not been able to go further. The only thing I have been able to has been to run calculations, for an upper limit of $m=1,000,000$, for increasing values of $N$.

As user21820 suspected, as a function of $N$, the sum oscillates. I was ewpecting smooth behaviors for odd or even values of $N$ but this is not the case.

The only apparent result is that, when $N$ increases more and more, the limit seems to be zero.